# Batch file check file get updated to today's date(System Date)

Tags: date, batch-file, modified-date

I want to create a batch to check if the file have been modified to today's date, what i did was to "bring in a system's date and compare it with the modified date, if they match, then trigger something.  My batch file works well and displays two right dates, but the IF statement saying the date mismatch.

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=. " %%i in ('date /t') do set date=%%k%%j
echo %date%
pause


FOR %%a IN (D:\MyFile.txt) DO SET FileDate=%%~ta
set DATEONLY=%FileDate:~0,10%
echo %DATEONLY%
pause



if DATEONLY==date (
echo date ok
) 

else (
cls
ECHO     Wrong
)

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 2):

There are the following problems:

- do *not* use variable name `date` as this is a built-in variable containing the current date (type `set /?` for help);
- the first `for` statement is useless, because `%date%` is already available;
- the strings `DATEONLY` and `date` are compared literally in your `if` statement, you need to state `%DATEONLY%==%date%` instead;
- the `else` statement *must* be in the same line as the closing parenthesis of the `if` body (type `if /?` for help);

So try this:

```
@ECHO OFF

echo %date%
pause

FOR %%a IN (D:\MyFile.txt) DO SET FileDate=%%~ta
set DATEONLY=%FileDate:~0,10%
echo %DATEONLY%
pause

if %DATEONLY%==%date% (
echo date ok
) else (
ECHO     Wrong
)
PAUSE
```

**Note:** Regard that all those dates in the batch file are locale-dependent.

Comment: so what is your date format when you enter `date /T` in the command prompt? is it the same as of `echo %Date%`? it should be... and what is the format of your `echo %FileDate%` value?? is it also the same (ignoring the time portion)??

Comment: date/T is 07/29/2015, same as %date%

Comment: echo %FileDate% value is 07/29/2015 11:20 AM

Comment: in order to convert that to similar format, i have to add [set DATEONLY=%FileDate:~0,10%]

Comment: yes, the line `set DATEONLY=%FileDate:~0,10%` truncates the time; but the line `for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=. " %%i in ('date /t') do set date=%%k%%j` has no effect, because you specify `. ` as delimiters but your date format uses `/`; so both `%%j` and `%%k` are empty and therefore the `for` body expands to `set date=`; the line `echo %date%` displays the date though because `%date%` is a built-in variable that (when not overwritten) expands to the current system date...

Comment: i just copy the code from some web, do you have anther way to get system date in 0730/2015 format?  @aschipfl

Comment: yes, just skip the said `for /f` line as it has no effect; `%date%` expands to the current date anyway...

Comment: i tested it, you can't skip for/f , because it will show Thur in front of the date, Thur is thursday

Comment: I don't get it... where does this "Thur" come from? [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527032/batch-file-check-file-get-updated-to-todays-datesystem-date/31527372?noredirect=1#comment51350839_31527372) you said the output format of `date /T` is `07/30/2015`... are you testing on different machines with different region settings each time??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely different approach:

```
forfiles /P . /M MyFile.txt /D +0 /C "cmd /C echo @fdate @file"
```

The `forfiles` command is capable of checking the file date. In the above command line, it:

- walks through the current directory (`.`),
- lists all files named `MyFile.txt` (of course there is onlyone),
- but only if it has been modified `+0` days after today,
- and then executed the command line after the `/C` switch.

If `MyFile.txt` has been modified today (or even in future), the given command line is executed;
if it has been modified earlier than today, an error message is displayed and `ERRORLEVEL` is set to `1`.

Notice that `forfiles` is not a built-in command and might not be available on your operating system.

Comment: I'd add this to your other answer instead of making a new answer, personally.

Comment: @SomethingDark, I was thinking about that too but I found this answer is too different as it does not even use the code of the original question. I searched the Help Center to find a best-practice for such situations but without success. Maybe there are some more opinions??

Comment: Thanks again!  I just posted a new question related to this, I hope you can help too.

Comment: @hben, I guess you are talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31547576/5047996), right?

Comment: @aschipfl, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547576/batch-file-compare-3-strings-in-a-row-multiple-strings?noredirect=1#comment51054163_31547576